# Assigning button ID dynamically and passing it via $.proxy()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple buttons are created using the each function. How can I give each button an id? Basically my need is to be able to pass the button id to `myFunc`.

This is what I've tried, but no luck.

```
var count=0;
$.each(xc, function(i, stNum) {
    count++;
$('<input class="colBtn" type="button">')
    .prop('id', 'p'+count)
    .on('click', $.proxy(myFunc, this.id))
    .appendTo ('#par2');
});

function myFunc(theID){
    alert(theID); //currently undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better pattern to use in this case is a delegated event handler. That way you don't need to attach an event hook in each iteration, and can use a single handler which reads the `id` property from the element which is clicked. Try this:

```
$.each(xc, function (i, color) {
    $('<input class="colBtn" type="button" />')
        .prop('id', 'p' + i)
        .appendTo('#par2');
});

$('#par2').on('click', '.colBtn', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vn6km3kd/)

Note that `count` is redundant as `i` is incremented with every iteration of the `each()` function.

---

***Update***

> what if I need to pass something like .on('click', $.proxy(myFunc, this.id, color[0]))

You can use `data-*` attributes to add ancillary data to an element which can then be read in the click handler:

```
$.each(xc, function (i, color) {
    $('<input class="colBtn" type="button" />')
        .prop('id', 'p' + i)
        .data('color', color[0])
        .appendTo('#par2');
});

$('#par2').on('click', '.colBtn', function() {
    alert(this.id);
    alert($(this).data('color'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks and looks good. But what if I need to pass something like `.on('click', $.proxy(myFunc, this.id, color[0]))`?

Comment: thanks again. Let me try implementing your suggeston into my code. :)